# Setting simple div to have size height and width 50% of body?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve that the width of the div is always 50% of the body. E.g. when I resize the window, the div should become smaller.

But the div size applied does not work at all when % is used.
[See here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJbFD)

What I don't want to do is to be forced to specify a width of body. Since that is exactly, that should be variable

CSS

```
.someclass{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #444444;
}



body {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="someclass"> </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a position absolute... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jlnIy

```
.someclass{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #444444;
}
```

Comment: Damn, posted just before me. I believe your correct.

Comment: alright I will accept this answer. The reason I posted it is btw because of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620196/downsizing-image-while-constraining-proportions

Comment: you're still constraining image dimensions to 50% of body height. Also you must realize the implications of setting `position: absolute` this way.

Comment: Actually, that makes the width 50% of the viewport, not 50% of body as requested by the question. Easiest way to see that is to change the width to 100%, which will not fit within the margins of body and cause a horizontal scroll bar to appear.