# Downsizing image while constraining proportions?

Tags: jquery, css

[I have this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjvLg) where I try to downsize an image, depending on the surrounding width. The problem is that it downsizes without constraining proportions.

HTML

```
the inline width and height come from wordpress and can luckily be successfully get overwritten by the class definition.
<br/>
<img src="http://artfiles.alphacoders.com/613/61309.jpg" width="4443" height="5555" class="someclass"/>
```

CSS

```
.someclass{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;

}



body {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Is there a neat way to do this in CSS, and if not, what is the cleanest way to do it with jquery?

Comment: Why is the image absolute?

Comment: if it is not absolute, width and height will have no influence

Comment: Then something else is wrong. `position: absolute` takes the element out of the flow and lets you set it's position based on its nearest `position: relative` parent. Positioning should have nothing to do with the elements size unless there are other things involved... right now, that relative parent is the window... hmmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep proportions you have to think what your percentage is "of." It's 50% of it's closest relatively positioned parent... in this case, the window since there is none... (which is why your absolute hack seems to work) Choose either width or height and leave the other auto. - base it on your understanding of it's parent. Take a gander at absolute vs relative and how they work together.

Is this an in-post media upload? if so, you can target it like this:

[(here is a jsFiddle of the following)](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/XLv5U/)

### HTML

```
<div class="main-content">

  <?php the_content(); ?>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.main-content img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
}

img.special-class { /* or like you have it, with a class - and the CSS above */
    property: value;
}
```

and you can use :nth of type to alternate floats and stuff.

If you are using a thumbnail... (featured image) or whatever...

Than I would use wrapper around the image for retina purposes (and generally have more control) and style the container's size and set your img like this:

### HTML

```
<div class="image-w">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.image-w {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: your-size;
}

.image-w img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
} /* this will set all img in .image-w's to respond to their parent */
```

Comment: that is even better. Didn't know the trick with `width` + `max-width`. Makes `position: absolute` obsolete.

Comment: The thing to note, is that it's not a trick. It's just the correct way of writing the rule(as of 2014 in a responsive environment of mulitple screens and squishy size-changing images). The absolute thing is just a fluke in this case. : )

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the attribute `height`:

```
$('.someclass').removeAttr('height');
```

and in your css class remove the height property:

```
.someclass{
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
}
```

#### [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jgzqi)

Comment: Make sure to also change the width and height of the image element to match the dimensions of the image.

Comment: Height's declared on image tag, he would need `height: auto;` removing the height property will make the height always `5555`.

Comment: edit your answer and I will accept. What you really want to add is this `.someclass{
   width: 50%;
   height: auto; /* see here */
   position: absolute;
}`

Comment: While inventive, both of these approaches will lead to problems very quickly once more elements are around. Using jQuery to remove a attribute, that you already have control over, is unnecessary and could have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

What is going on is that you are setting the width and height of the image element to be 50% of whatever contains is, not 50% of its original width and height. That is why it isn't being sized proportionally. If you wanted to do this in pure css you could try something like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lzaej

In which the image was replaced with a div and then the image itself we set as a background. The css properties I use though might not be supported in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat inline HTML code that assigns width as a percent then sets height with correct proportion try this...

```
<img src="http://www.yourwebste/imageurl.jpg" height=65% width= height/width*65%>
```

This example has 65% (twice) but you could change this to any